# Neo4j-import fails

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I'm trying to import a dataset using neo4j-import. Unfortunately the import fails with the following error message which is not saying much to me. Does anyone has an idea?

Thank you

The command was:

./neo4j-import --into /home_expes/dd77474h/neo4j-community-3.0.7/data/databases/graph.db/ --nodes /home_expes/dd77474h/Indexing-server/reduced_dbpedia_nodes.csv  --relationships /home_expes/dd77474h/Indexing-server/reduced_dbpedia_relations.csv --stacktrace  true --id-type

reduced_dbpedia_nodes.csv:

id:ID,uri,:LABEL
7,"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albedo",Resource

reduced_dbpedia_relations.csv

:START_ID,:END_ID,:TYPE
1,2,"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type"

Error message:

Relationship --> Relationship Sparse
[>:231.50 MB/s--------------------------|LINK(3)==|*v:130.76 MB/s-----------------------------] 171M

Done in 24s 824ms

Minority relationships
[*INSERT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 540K

Done in 14m 31s 126ms

Count groups
[*>:??----------------------------------------------------------------------------|COUNT------]12.2M
Done in 2s 786ms

Gather

java.lang.RuntimeException: Panic called, so exiting
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.assertHealthy(AbstractStep.java:155)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep.process(ProducerStep.java:84)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep$1.run(ProducerStep.java:54)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There's no room for me for startIndex:28899 with a group count of -25966. This means that there's an asymmetry between calls to incrementGroupCount and actual contents sent into put
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.RelationshipGroupCache.scanForFreeFrom(RelationshipGroupCache.java:203)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.RelationshipGroupCache.put(RelationshipGroupCache.java:159)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.CacheGroupsStep.process(CacheGroupsStep.java:48)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.CacheGroupsStep.process(CacheGroupsStep.java:31)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProcessorStep.lambda$receive$2(ProcessorStep.java:97)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:243)

Import error: Panic called, so exiting

Caused by:Panic called, so exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Panic called, so exiting
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.assertHealthy(AbstractStep.java:155)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep.process(ProducerStep.java:84)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep$1.run(ProducerStep.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There's no room for me for startIndex:28899 with a group count of -25966. This means that there's an asymmetry between calls to incrementGroupCount and actual contents sent into put
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.RelationshipGroupCache.scanForFreeFrom(RelationshipGroupCache.java:203)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.RelationshipGroupCache.put(RelationshipGroupCache.java:159)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.CacheGroupsStep.process(CacheGroupsStep.java:48)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.CacheGroupsStep.process(CacheGroupsStep.java:31)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProcessorStep.lambda$receive$2(ProcessorStep.java:97)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:243)

Comment: Hi, I'm Mattias main author of the import tool. I haven't seen that error before and am not sure about the nature of it. The best way to solve this would be if I could personally get a hold of the CSV input files to reproduce locally and debug my way to the issue. Would that be possible?

Comment: Hi Mattias, it took a while but now I put the files online. You can find them under https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwTC1WSK11-WX2QyVC1uRG53LTA Thank you Dennis

Comment: Thank you very much, got 'em now... I'll investigate and get back to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I found the bug. FYI see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/8778 for fix.